# Script no abre el csv que está en la misma carpeta

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, plotly, dash

Cuando llamo a un script `app.py` que llama a otro script `attributes.py` que lee un csv, este último no parece estar presente para `attributes.py`.

En efecto, cuando hizo:

```
python app.py
```

Me sale:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error está aquí en formato de texto:

```
(venv) C:\Users\antoi\PycharmProjects\Bass>python app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pages import header, attributes#, similarity,
  File "C:\Users\antoi\PycharmProjects\Bass\pages\attributes.py", line 14, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv("cb_pb.csv", index_col=0)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\PycharmProjects\Bass\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 688, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\PycharmProjects\Bass\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 454, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\PycharmProjects\Bass\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 948, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\PycharmProjects\Bass\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1180, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\PycharmProjects\Bass\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2010, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 382, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 674, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cb_pb.csv'
```

Y aquí esta `attributes.py`:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv("cb_pb.csv", index_col=0)


def layout():
    return html.Div([
        html.H1(children='Scores of perfumes over claimed attributes'),
        html.Div(children='''National Sales Funnel Report.'''),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='perfume-dropdown',
            options=[{'label': x, 'value': x} for x in df.index.unique()],
            value='My Burberry - Eau de Parfum'
        ),
        html.Div(id='dd-output-container'),
        html.Div([
            dcc.Graph(id='the_graph')
        ])
    ])

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='the_graph', component_property='figure'),
    [Input(component_id="perfume-dropdown", component_property="value")]
)
def update_graph(my_dropdown):
    dfc = df.sort_values(by='perceived_benefit', ascending=False)
    traces = []
    for i in range(len(dfc)):
        if dfc.iloc[i].name == my_dropdown:
            trace_claimed = go.Bar(x=[dfc.iloc[i].values[0]], y=[dfc.iloc[i].values[2]], name='Claimed')
            trace_perceived = go.Bar(x=[dfc.iloc[i].values[0]], y=[-dfc.iloc[i].values[1]], name='Perceived')
            traces.append(trace_claimed)
            traces.append(trace_perceived)
    figure={
        'data': traces,
        'layout':
            go.Layout(title='Score des parfums sur les attributs', barmode='stack')
    }

    return figure

@app.callback(
    Output('dd-output-container', 'children'),
    [Input('perfume-dropdown', 'value')])
def update_output(value):
    return 'You have selected "{}"'.format(value)

# if __name__ == '__main__':
#     app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

### Explicación

El directorio desde donde ejecutas la aplicación es `Bass/venv/` donde se encuentra el archivo `app.py`, este es tu directorio base (o working directory) y todos los directorios que utilices en tu programa deben tenerlo en cuenta.

El archivo `attributes.py` ha sido llamado a través de `app.py` y su directorio base ahora es el mismo de `app.py` desde donde está siendo ejecutado.

Para acceder a tu archivo sería necesario este directorio: `../pages/cb_pb.csv`.

La primera parte del directorio `../` es necesaria para salir de la carpeta `venv` en la que se encuentra el directorio base y luego poder acceder a `pages/cb_pb.csv` si es necesario subir más carpetas se puede hacer algo como `../../` las veces que sea necesario.

Ahora bien, esta no es la mejor forma de hacerlo ya que si importas el módulo desde otro lugar o lo ejecutas de forma directa dará un error al no encontrar este archivo debido a que el directorio base ha cambiado.

---

### Solución

Una solución más práctica sería la de utilizar la librería `pathlib` ([documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)) en tu archivo `attributes.py` con la que puedes obtener el directorio del mismo aunque este haya sido ejecutado desde `app.py`. Podrías hacerlo de esta manera:

```
import pathlib

# Directorio de este archivo py
EsteScript = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()
```

También te recomiendo que utilices `os.path` para lidiar con los `/` `\` de las direcciones ya que la orientación de estos cambian según el sistema operativo en el que te encuentres:

```
from os import path

Directorio = path.join(EsteScript, 'cb_pb.csv')
```

---

### Ejemplo completo

**Estructura de carpetas:**

```
test
   'run.py'
    modulo_a  
       'attributes.py'
       'file.txt'
       '__init__.py'
```

**Contenido de run.py:**

```
print("Ejecutando attributes...")

from modulo_a import attributes
```

**Contenido de attributes.py:**

```
import pathlib
from os import path

# Directorio de este archivo py
EsteScript = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute() 

filePath = path.join(EsteScript, 'file.txt')

with open(filePath, 'r') as f:
    print(f)
```

**Contenido de file.txt:**

```
Hola Mundo!!!
```

> El archivo `__init__.py` no tiene contenido porque sirve solo para que el interprete Python identifique la carpeta `modulo_a` como un modulo y permita importar los archivos `.py` de ella en el proyecto.

**Devuelve:**

```
Ejecutando attributes...
Hola Mundo!!!
```